# How to add a Display attribute to an external enum?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using enums for some properties which have only a certain number of options
(e.g. Gender). I render these enums using `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(...)` which uses the `Display` attribute to correctly render the options (these values come from a resource because they need to be translatable).

```
public enum Gender
{
    [Display(Name = "LabelMale", ResourceType = typeof(Translation))]
    Male,
    [Display(Name = "LabelFemale", ResourceType = typeof(Translation))]
    Female
}
```

But these enums come from an external project that cannot be edited or do not have access to the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace.
So I cannot add the required `Display` attributes to the values in these enum.

The viewmodels have the same problem, but for the viewmodels I can use the `MetadataType(...)` attribute.

However this does not work on enums.

Is there a similiar solution so I can have translatable enums?

Comment: Did you think of defining your own enums and writing a class to do the conversion between yours and the external project? If there are a lot of them, reflection would come in handy too.

Comment: @Hamed Yes I've consider this, but I was hoping there is a better solution already in asp.net so I do not have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [TypeDesciptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx) to add an attribute at runtime. One problem could occure during reading those attributes from the `asp.net-mvc` framework, if they do not use `TypeDescriptor` for resolving those attributes.

But you could give it a try.

Comment: After initial testing it looked like `EnumDropDownListFor()` did not use the `TypeConverter` I've just confirmed this, the asp.net MVC 5.2.2  does not utilize the `TypeDescriptor`. It uses `EnumHelper.GetDisplayName()` which only read the `Display` attribute.(https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/66298100f4e3#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs)

Comment: Currently looking at https://github.com/nuhusky/gizmo-helpers/blob/master/Helpers/Html/EnumHtmlHelperExtensions.cs which does work when the `TypeConverter` is added to the enum, now looking to add it to the propery instead of the enum itself.